# Linear Algebra - Changing bases?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $T: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$ be the linear transformation defined by $T((a,b,c)) = \begin{bmatrix}a&5a\\c&3c\end{bmatrix}$. Consider the bases $\alpha=\left\{(0,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,1,0)\right\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $\beta=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ of $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{R})$. Find $\left[\strut T\right]_\alpha^\beta$.

Here is the question I've been struggling with. I am a little new to changing bases and coordinates etc.

Either way, it looks like I'm trying to find a transformation matrix that somehow also changes the bases? And how can I go from a vector to a $2\times2$ matrix? I know this is allowed in linear transformation but this question is just very confusing to me and any help is much appreciated.

I've tried some different things with change of basis matrices and some tranformation matrices but it all seems to be a dead end.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE!  Here's a [handy guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to mark up math nicely on this site. I've already done this for your question in a pending edit.

Comment: It's already difficult enough to change bases going from vectors to vectors. It might seem as though this problem is even more difficult than that. But it's not. The matrices here really don't play any role as matrices - they are just vectors written in a rectangular array. So the first thing to do to avoid confusion might be to rewrite each matrix $\pmatrix{a & b \\ c& d}$ as a vector $(a,b,c,d)$. Then will the question be familiar enough to you that you can handle it?

Comment: Well I've changed the 2x2 matrices to vectors in R^4. I'm not actually 100% sure how to start on this problem but I set up a change-of-basis matrix using the vectors in α as the columns. So if I have some generic vector in R^3 that represent coordinates in α, I can change them to coordinates in the Standard Basis, not sure where to go from there. 

Sorry about the formatting I'm working on learning it

Comment: You need three pieces of information: (1) the $4 \times 3$ matrix $M$ of $T$ with respect to the standard bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$;  (2) the $3 \times 3$ transition matrix $P$ of the basis $\alpha$ (with the basis vectors for columns); (3) the $4 \times 4$ transition matrix $Q$ of the basis $\beta$. Then the matrix $M'$ that you require is given by $M' = Q^{-1}MP$. You should write these matrices down so we can maybe comment on whether you've done it correctly. Click on "edit" to see how Frentos coded your formulas for you.